# I can't run cocoalibspotify's sample code properly

Tags: spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0, libspotify

I got cocoalibspotify at
https://github.com/spotify/cocoalibspotify

When I run the project,
an alert come up saying "Login Details Missing. The username, password or both are missing. Please consult the testing part of the readme file."

Before alert comes up, there is a code to get password and username datas.

```
NSString *userName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:kTestUserNameUserDefaultsKey];
NSString *password = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:kTestPasswordUserDefaultsKey];
```

So I filled these information at TestConstants.h.
But same error occurs.

How can I resolve the problem?

---

[update]
I still can't run the project.  I found code I can't run is test unit of this library.  But I  succeeded in running sample codes attached to CocoaLibSpotify.  Still I want to solve this problem, but I'm not in hurry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, "Please consult the testing part of the readme file". Exact instructions for fixing the problem are in the Testing part of the readme file - adding them to TestConstants.h isn't the fix.

Comment: Everything goes fine!  I should have read readme file well.  Thank you very much!